# iOS app submission error : ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon29x29'"

Tags: ios, image

I tried to submit my archive to the App Store. I keep getting the following errors:

```
ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon29x29'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon40x40'"

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'"
```

I am sure I set all the app icons, but I still got the same error. I have published apps before. I followed the same process. I am using Xcode 6.3.

I have checked the related questions, many suggested to remove the CarPlay icon. But, I don't see such icon after I click into the appicons. The only icons required are of size: 58x58, 87x87, 80x80, 120x120, and 180x180. I didn't see anywhere that requests icons of size: 29x29, 40x40, or 60x60. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: I've got the same thing here.

Answer (score 5):

Probably, the image is not in PNG format.

Remember, just renaming the image to .png doesn't make it a png image. To convert an image to PNG, follow the below steps: 
1. Open image in Preview
2. File > Export > Choose PNG from Drop Down Menu > OK
3. Save the PNG Image in desired location

Use this png image in AppIcon.appiconset .

Comment: Helped very much. Problem was that online icon generator consumed .JPG file and output .PNG but it was in real still .JPG